# How to force all local users to change their password

Tags: users, password

I'm Currently following [RHCSA](https://www.redhat.com/en/services/certification/rhcsa). Can you guys tell me way to force all local users to change their password in next login?

Comment: First order post-it-notes. The users will use these to write there now password on. Most of what we do as IT managers to enforce password policies, make your system **less** secure. Do training. For a real world example see USA prohibition of alcohol and its effect.

Comment: @ctrl-alt-delor No worries. Hopefully they are able to just change it to whatever they originally used.

Answer (score 1):

There are other users besides root that are daemons (process managers) that you shouldn't change.

I suggest the following command issued as root:

```bsh
for user in $(grep "/home" /etc/passwd | cut -s -d':' -f1)
do
    passwd -e $user
done
```

Always test sections of code, especially before applying a command modifying users ability to login. You may have to undo your work in a hurry if you get it wrong.

Try the following first, to ensure you have a valid list of users from whom you wish to expire their password:

```bsh
grep "/home" /etc/passwd | cut -s -d':' -f1
```

From the [cut(1)](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man1/cut.1.html) man page:

```
cut - remove sections from each line of files

-s, --only-delimited
              do not print lines not containing delimiters

-d, --delimiter=DELIM
              use DELIM instead of TAB for field delimiter

-f, --fields=LIST
              select only these fields;  also print any line that contains
              no delimiter character, unless the -s option is specified
```

My suggestion is to create a new user, try `passwd -e` on that username, logout and login to verify that the expected behaviour is obtained before applying the same command to other users.

Comment: I didn't get that can u explain please. what is the meaning of cut -s -d':' -f1 ?

Comment: @Wasantha See updated answer.

Comment: @Kusalananda updated my answer.

Comment: @PauloTomé Fair enough, I was more thinking about the command that actually _does_ something to the system, the `passwd -e` command. Is this safe to run on one's own account, for example, as you suggest? What would be the expected behaviour when doing that?

Comment: @Kusalananda You are right. It is not safe to run the script on one's own account. Updated my answer.